# No me trae los datos en handlebars node.js

Tags: nodejs, handlebars.js

Hola amigos tengo un problema no me trae todos los datos como deberia ser.

```
 <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link Light" href="/registros">Personas</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/registros/persona">Agregar Persona</a>
    </li>
    <h1>{{user}}</h1>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown margin-left">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"
            aria-expanded="false">Usuario</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/iniciar_sesion">Iniciar sesion</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/registrarse">Cerrar sesion</a></li>
            <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
```

la variable {{user}} me trae la información que yo quiero
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando llamo especificamente el dato que quiero en este caso es name pongo {{user.name}} no me trae nada codigo de la logica que lo trae es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi traigo los datos en el model

```
    //modulos necesarios para crear la logica de creación de usuario
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

//Se parametriza el Schema del user para que registrar las variables en una variable y que indiquen su valor
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})



 UserSchema.methods.encryptPassword = async (password) => {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hash = bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
        return hash
    }
    
    UserSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (password) {
        return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password)
    }
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

la funcion authenticated es la que trae la información del usuario

```
const helpers = {}
helpers.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next()
    }
    req.flash('error_msg', 'No autorizado')
    res.redirect('/users/iniciar_sesion')
}

module.exports = helpers
```

Por medio de la funcion isAuthenticated esta guarda los datos del usuario registrado

Comment: ¿Cómo estás pasando las variables a tu plantilla? Hace falta más código para poder entender el problema, por favor trata de mostrar un [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Listo ahi puse el model que es donde consulta la tabal user de mongodb