# Como poner un dato especifico de un json con node.js

Tags: nodejs, handlebars.js

Hola amigos tengo la siguiente funcion que trae los datos de un usuario y esta se trae por json

```
   app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg')
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg')
    res.locals.user = req.user
    next()
})
```

Especificamente  la linea que dice res.locals.user = req.user

me devuelve esto imprimiendolo en .hbs: `<h1>{{user}}</h1>`
{ _id: 60eb2bedc7346e132859d2ca, name: 'Andres', email: 'a@gmail.com', password: '$2a$10$3H1Sen/ehjQGgCzELbMT3ejora26Y6ychllYnXYfk9gfI2bUMPLM.', date: 2021-07-11T17:35:41.648Z, __v: 0 }
pero cuando escribo `<h1>{{user.name}}</h1>` no me trae el dato especifico que le digo
estos datos son traigos de el authenticador de usuario

```
const helpers = {}
helpers.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next()
    }
    req.flash('error_msg', 'No autorizado')
    res.redirect('/users/iniciar_sesion')
}

module.exports = helpers
```

Comment: Tal vez `user` no es un objeto, sino una cadena (`string`) en formato JSON. Prueba hacer lo siguiente: `res.locals.user = JSON.parse(req.user);` o en todo caso, muestra cómo estás pasando tu variable `user` a la plantilla de `handlebars`. Ya te pedí que mostrarás esa parte en tu [otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/468203/no-me-trae-los-datos-en-handlebars-node-js) pregunta. Por favor, no dupliques preguntas. Saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No me trae los datos en handlebars node.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/468203/no-me-trae-los-datos-en-handlebars-node-js)